# Intersection of normal subgroups in a surface group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $S_g$ be the fundamental group of a genus $g$ orientable surface.  Suppose that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two infinite index nontrivial normal subgroups in $S_g$ (hence they are free of infinite rank).

Is it necessarily true that $N_1 \cap N_2$ is nontrivial?

Comment: Isn't the trivial subgroup normal and of infinite index?

Comment: Sorry - intended for those groups to be nontrivial - I edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. We have $[N_1,N_2]\subset N_1\cap N_2$, and actually $[N_1,N_2]\neq 1$ as soon as $N_1\neq 1\neq N_2$ (infinite index is not the point).

Indeed, $S_g$ ($g\ge 2$) can be embedded in a Zariski-dense way in the simple complex group $PGL_2$. If $M_i$ is the Zariski closure of $N_i$, then $M_i$ is normal in $PGL_2$ and $[M_1,M_2]=1$, which implies that either $M_1$ or $M_2$ is reduced to 1, hence either $N_1$ or $N_2$ is reduced to 1.

This is one approach, there are many others.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you mention how that embedding works?  And also possibly briefly mention some of the other approaches that you have in mind.

Comment: I leave other approaches to other contributors, e.g. using the amalgam decomposition (maybe look in basis combinatorial group theory textbooks).  The embedding follows when you describe $S_g$ as fundamental group of some oriented closed hyperbolic surface. Then the action of $S_g$ on the universal cover, the hyperbolic plane, is by oriented isometries, and this group is precisely $\mathrm{PSL}(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: For another approach, for every nontrivial element $x \in \pi_1(S_g)$ its centralizer $C(x)$ is an infinite cyclic, malnormal subgroup (proved using the deck action of $\pi_1(S_g)$ on the hyperbolic plane associated to a hyperbolic structure on $S_g$). Pick $n_1 \in N_1$ and $n_2 \in N_2$ so that neither is contained in the centralizer of the other; this is possible because $N_1,N_2$ are not cyclic. It follows that $[n_1,n_2]$ is nontrivial.